# What dangers should I keep in mind while driving in the Dominican Republic?

Tags: car-rentals, dominican-republic

I  heard a lot of scary stuff about driving in the Dominican Republic. While I realize, that a foreign country can have very very different habits than I'm used to, I wouldn't like to end up in jail or similar.

I'll be visiting the Dominican Republic soon and I'd like to have a good idea of what's it like there. I plan to rent a car in the mid-south of the island and drive to the north to visit the so-called 21 waterfalls.

I have experience driving in Moscow (I'm Russian) and I drove a lot in Europe (I live in Germany).

The general question is: how can I maximize my security, what insurances should I buy, etc, etc, so as not to get problems in DR and manage a good time? I have heard of things such as Casa del Conductor, and similar insurances. I'm hoping to hear from people with experience.

Comment: @LLIAMnYP I'm sure that if you can survive Russian roads, you can survive DR.  However, I've never been to DR, so I don't know what it's like there :)

Comment: @LLIAMnyP - The TripAdvisor website has IMO some very informative posts about driving in DR. The advice is overwhelmingly (but not solely) against driving there. Here are two links that I hope you'll find useful:

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g147293-i28-k10332771-Driving_in_Dominican_Republic-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html

------------------------------

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g147288-i27-k6471066-Renting_a_Car_and_Driving_in_DR-Dominican_Republic.html